# "Get-PnPProperty: Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject"

Tags: pnp-powershell

When we run the below command on Powershell 7, to fetch detail of folder in the sharepoint.

```
Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject "david onedve/3200 in 400mb/Level 2" -Property Files, Folders
```

,
we are getting below error:
*Get-PnPProperty: Cannot bind parameter 'ClientObject'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder" value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject".*

However, its run successfully on Powershell 5.1

Answer (score 0):

The PnP module is not compatible with PowerShell 7 as PnP requires .NET Framework and PowerShell 7 uses .NET Core.